# Any way to detect client disconnet in Ktor server

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I'm trying to make a proxy server by ktor, it proxy a http-flv infinite stream, after client close, it should do something to release resource. like

```kotlin
client.get<HttpStatement>(url.value.url).execute { response ->
    val channel: ByteReadChannel = response.receive()
    while (!channel.isClosedForRead) {
        logger.info("status ${call.request.receiveChannel().isClosedForRead}")
        val packet = channel.readRemaining(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong())
        logger.info("flushing...")
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            write(packet.readBytes())
            flush()
        }
    }
    // do something to clean resource
}
```

try to use router event and flush writer, didn't work

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what resources do you want to release? Also, a client can be closed only by an explicit `close` call.

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is to wrap your code in `try/finally` and put a code for cleaning resources in a `finally` block.